# Fenics: Meshfunction usage

Tags: fenics

I am confused most of the time with the application of boundary conditions in Fenics. Suppose I have an xml mesh for a rectangular beam and want to apply Dirichlet BC ($u =0$) on the left side of the beam in my mesh file. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

I know another way of doing it by defining subdomains like here:

```
class Left(SubDomain):
def inside(self, x, on_boundary):
    return near(x[0], 0.0)
```

But for complicated geometries, I am sure this method is not useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That depends how did you generated the file. For example your mesh generator can produce some cell or facet markers according to its input. Then `dolfin-convert` script may or may not succeed converting all these markers to XML. They're then stored within XML mesh file or in separate XML. You can then use them as `FacetFunction`

```
# if stored within mesh
facet_domains = mesh.domains().facet_domains(mesh) # older versions of DOLFIN
facet_domains = mesh.domains().facet_domains() # newer versions of DOLFIN

# if stored separately
facet_domains = MeshFunction('uint', mesh, file) # older versions of DOLFIN
facet_domains = MeshFunction('size_t', mesh, file) # newer versions of DOLFIN

# now define homogenous Dirichlet BC where facet_domains is equal to 42
bc42 = DirichletBC(V, 0.0, facet_domains, 42)

# now integrate over interior facets where facet_domains equals 43
dS = Measure('dS')[facet_domains]
dS43 = dS(43)
integral43 = foo*dS43
```

If your mesh generator does not supply you with markers you need, you can produce first these markers using `EntityIterators`, for example

```
facet_domains = FacetFunction('size_t', mesh, 0)
for c in cells(mesh):
    # here some conditions on c
    for f in facets(c):
        # here some conditions on f
        facet_domains[f] = some_computed_value
```

Then you can use these `facet_domains` as suggested above.

---

**Application of `DirichletBC` at one particular vertex**

Defining `DirichletBC` in one vertex is not possible through `MeshFunction`s as `DirichletBC` only supports `FacetFunction`s. But you can take advantage of `DirichletBC(..., method='pointwise')` and do something like:

```
import numpy as np

class Pinpoint(SubDomain):
    TOL = 1e-3
    def __init__(self, coords):
        self.coords = np.array(coords)
        SubDomain.__init__(self)
    def move(self, coords):
        self.coords[:] = np.array(coords)
    def inside(self, x, on_boundary):
        return np.linalg.norm(x-self.coords) < TOL

pinpoint = Pinpoint([0.,0.,0.])

V = VectorFunctionSpace(mesh, "Lagrange", 1)
bc = DirichletBC(V.sub(0), 0.0, pinpoint, 'pointwise')
```

Note that this has only meaning for `V` being continuous piecewise linear functions. Constructor `Pinpoint.__init__` takes an `coords` argument (of type `tuple`, `list` or `np.array`) allowing of specification of coordinates where you want to apply BC. Also method `Pinpoint.move` can be useful to change this point without a need of creating new `DirichletBC` instance - especially when `mesh` moves.

Another possibility is to directly fiddle with `Tensor`s' entries.

Comment: I will try this function but am little bit clear about your message. thnks

Comment: Hi Jan..I tried to work with your idea but little bit confused..I have 88 vertices, 190 cells (3D) in my mesh file and suppose i want to fix x displacement of vertices 84 can you just assist me to do that ??

Comment: @nickrocks: You need to provide more information. I guess you want to apply `DirichletBC` on some `Function` - what `FunctionSpace` is it from? How are these Dirichlet vertices defined?

Comment: I clarify little bit more..I imported a mesh file which contains vertices (88) and cells in order..                
mesh = Mesh("thick_plate_tet_1stOrder.xml")


# Define function space and basis functions
V = VectorFunctionSpace(mesh, "Lagrange", 1)
U = TrialFunction(V)
v = TestFunction(V)
and I want to fix x direction of displacement only for a particular node (0,0,0) defined in meshfile....how should I do that??

Comment: @nickrocks: Suggestion added to my answer.

Comment: thnks Jan now it's pretty clear