# How to use MeshFunction in FEniCS (dolfin)?

Tags: pde, python, fenics

I'm a beginner user of FEniCS and still struggling with some of the basics. Specifically,
I have some issues doing the tutorials in the Langtangen-Logg book *Solving PDEs in Python - The FEniCS Tutorial Volume I*. I think some of the problems are due to the different versions of the book and my installation (2019.1.0).

One of the issues is the use of the `MeshFunction` or `CellFunction`, `FacetFunction`, etc.

The example (4.3.2 on page 90) says:

```
materials = CellFunction(’size_t’, mesh)
```

which doesn't work for me. After some research I found out that `CellFunction` is deprecated since 2017.2.0:
*Deprecate VertexFunction, EdgeFunction, FaceFunction, FacetFunction, CellFunction; use MeshFunction instead*

I got the example to work with some trial and error (at least it looks like it's working):

```
materials = MeshFunction('size_t', mesh, 2)
```

But I do not really understand how and why. Especially after trying the next example that uses `FacetFunction`.

The [2017.2.0 doc](https://fenicsproject.org/docs/dolfin/2017.2.0/python/programmers-reference/cpp/mesh/MeshFunction.html) doesn't say much about how to use `MeshFunction`. The descripton for the `dim (unsigned int)` argument says:
*The topological dimension of the MeshFunction. Optional.*

The description for `CellFunction` is just:
*Create MeshFunction of topological codimension 0 on given mesh.*
For `FacetFunction`:
*Create MeshFunction of topological codimension 1 on given mesh.*

It doesn't work with `materials = MeshFunction('size_t', mesh, 0)`. I figured that the *codimension 0* might mean to use `0` for the `dim` argument in the case of "CellFunction".

Therefore, my questions are:

1. Is the "codimension" referring to the `dim` argument?
2. What does "topological dimension" and "topological codimension" mean in this context?
3. If I should use `MeshFunction` instead of all those other functions mentioned above, how does using MeshFunction for cells differ from using it for facets, etc.

PS: I am aware of the question [Fenics: Meshfunction usage](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7330/fenics-meshfunction-usage/7332), but it doesn't really answer my question

Comment: You might get (or already find!) better answers at https://fenicsproject.discourse.group/, but you need to give the (no longer optional) topological dimension using `MeshFunction('size_t',mesh,mesh.topology().dim())` (for cells in 2d, use `mesh.topology().dim()-1` for facets and `mesh.topology(),dim()-2` for vertices). This is described in [this commented demo](https://fenicsproject.org/docs/dolfin/2019.1.0/python/demos/subdomains/documentation.html). Always make sure that what you're looking at (even if it's a book) matches the version you are using (which you didn't specify).

Comment: Thank you! I added the version in the question (2019.1.0). I'd love to do a tutorial that matches my installation, but the mentioned book looked like the best recent tutorial I could find. And it's also recommended on the FEniCS website. Installing and learning an old version didn't seem like a good way either, that's why I try to adjust the examples

Comment: The FEniCS website explicitly warns that the examples in the tutorial are obsolete :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The different specialized `VertexFunction`, `EdgeFunction`, `FaceFunction`, `FacetFunction`, `CellFunction` have indeed been deprecated and (at least) as of version 2018.2 removed. Instead, they have been merged into a general purpose `MeshFunction` which takes the kind of mesh object they're defined on as a (mandatory) parameter called the "topological dimension".

To understand what to put there, it may be helpful to stress the differences between *geometric* objects (points, lines, polygons, polyhedra) and *topological* objects (vertices, edges, facets, cells) -- while the former have the same dimension (basically by definition) no matter what the definition of the ambient space is (the "n" in "nD"), the latter do not, since they depend on the role they play in forming the mesh. These are instead distinguished by they *codimension*, which is "n minus geometric dimension" (how far they are from "full space"):

- **cells** have (by definition) **codimension 0**
- **facets** have (by definition) **codimension 1** (boundaries of cells)
- **edges** have (by definition) **codimension n-1**
- **vertices** have (by definition) **codimension n** (boundaries of edges)

For example, in 1D a line (geometric dimension 1) is a cell (codimension 0=1-1), while in 2D it's a facet (codimension 1=2-1)
(These can overlap: In 2D, edges and facets are the same; in 1D, facets and vertices are (and edges make no sense).)

---

Back to FEniCS: As the above tried to illustrate, mesh objects are described by their *codimension*; nevertheless, `MeshFunction` takes the actual (geometric) dimension, which by simple arithmetic is "n minus codimension". To write this in a dimension-independent way, you can make use of the function `mesh.topology().dim() So for example, to mark

- **cells**, use `MeshFunction('size_t',mesh,mesh.topology().dim())`
- **facets**, use `MeshFunction('size_t',mesh,mesh.topology().dim()-1)`
- **edges**, use `MeshFunction('size_t',mesh,1)`
- **vertices**, use `MeshFunction('size_t',mesh,0)`

**DISCLAIMER:** This is valid for versions **2018.1** to **2019.1**.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest version of FEniCS, the meshing tools are deprecated as you've noticed. These tools are now under `mshr` module.
You can install it via terminal: `conda install -c conda-forge mshr`

Additionally, if you'd like to convert meshes, the `dolfin-convert` became deprecated as well. The functions are now bundled in `meshio` module. Similarly: `conda install -c kayarre meshio`

The usage in both cases should be the similar as described in older dolfin/FEniCS documentation.

Comment: I'm using 2019.1.0, `MeshFunction` still seems to work even without `mshr`. However, I have mshr installed, but I do not understand how  to make the above mentioned example work with or without mshr. The mshr doc doesn't seem to have a `MeshFunction`. Are there docs or tutorials that explain how the "old" way translates to how to do it in the newer versions?

Comment: Feel free to ask those questions on Discourse Group. https://fenicsproject.discourse.group/ By all means I'm trying to avoid using mshr for that particular reason and I'm importing mesh created external tool.